# ¿ Como detectar cuando un punto choca con otro?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Hola Mundo.**

Estoy tratando de poder intersectar la colisión de dos puntos trazados por el touch. Es decir necesito saber cuando el usuario al mover su dedo por la pantalla choca con un punto pasado y guardado. Pero por ahora se me esta complicando.

**Mi código:**

```
List<int[]> puntos_ocupados = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            for(int[] ocupado : puntos_ocupados){

                if((int) event.getX() > (ocupado[0] - 12) && (int) event.getX() < (ocupado[0] + 12)){
                   if((int) event.getY() > (ocupado[1] - 12) && (int) event.getY() < (ocupado[1] + 12)){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "perdio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                if((int) event.getX() == (ocupado[0]) && (int) event.getY() == (ocupado[1])){
                       Toast.makeText(context, "perdio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                System.out.println("punto x:" + ocupado[0] + " y:"+ocupado[1]);
                System.out.println("___punto x:" + event.getX() + " y:"+event.getY());
            }

        puntos_ocupados.add(new int[]{(int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()});
                break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Uso dos métodos uno en donde coloco un tamaño al punto pasado (guardado) y lo determino si el dedo o el pulso en el touch al arrastrarlo cocha o se intersecta con el punto pasado (guardado):

```
if((int) event.getX() > (ocupado[0] - 12) && (int) event.getX() < (ocupado[0] + 12)){
     if((int) event.getY() > (ocupado[1] - 12) && (int) event.getY() < (ocupado[1] + 12)){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "perdio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
                
 }
```

Tambien tengo otra forma que me determina el punto exacto:

```
if((int) event.getX() == (ocupado[0]) && (int) event.getY() == (ocupado[1])){
   Toast.makeText(context, "perdio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Pero de las dos las dos fallan :(.

Espero su apoyo y **gracias por adelantado.**

Comment: punto con otro punto eso es como un array haciendo filter de tal punto si encuentra tendra el array items. Ahi decides que hacer si hay items es que ya existe.   Guarda tus puntos en un array que sea objetos (ej: coordinates).

Comment: Amigo ahi uso un List el cual almacena todos los puntos pero el problema es necesito detectar el punto donde se se paso el dedo y por donde se paso el dedo.

Comment: usa un objeto una clase donde tenga x y y, con un filter(funcion de lista o array) averiguas si hay un punto igual a ese o no.

Comment: El problema no es comparar el problema es determinar de acuerdo al pulso del dedo en el touch al ser arrastrado si cayo o no en el hueco.

Comment: Entonces no es punto por punto, es si un punto se encuentra dentro de una forma(shape). Si es un cuadrado es facil con la clase Rect. Pero si es una forma personalizada, tendras que obtener los puntos hay clases que te ayudan en obtener los puntos de un path. La clase Path creo, obtienes los puntos y entonces comparas con un for cuando este adrento o afuera le das break. hasta puedes obtener los puntos de un bitmap su forma si esta en png, aqui el github :https://github.com/harjot-oberai/MaterialShadows , Puedes usar una imagen para tu forma si no pillas de la que te digo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  Si me escribes una respuesta con path te la acepto.